# Freemarker iterating over List<List>>

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to iterate over a List < Lits < Record > > with Freemaker. I have tried this but it is not working:

```
 <#list keyTranslations as keyTranslation>         
        <tr>
            <#list keyTranslation as translation>         
                <td style="padding:5px;">
                    ${translation.translationValue}
                </td>
            </#list> 
        </tr>
    </#list>
```

Does someone know how can I do it?

Comment: It's done as you do it. What's not working, like what error do you get?

Comment: this is my error: FreeMarker template error:
For "#list" list source: Expected a sequence or collection, but this evaluated to an extended_hash (HashMap wrapped into f.t.DefaultMapAdapter):

Comment: I guess that error points to the 2nd list, which means that `keyTranslations` is a `List` of `Map`-s, not a `List` of `List`-s.